# Draw line between two points (x1,y1,z1) to (x2,y2,z2)

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cgcontext, catransform3d

I know how to draw line on 2d surface.But I can't find a way to draw a line in space.

I have wrote a demo

[image]

and now I want to draw line in space.

and finish it like this:

[image]

I have finished the 2d surface rotate in space use CATransform3D already. But I don't know how to draw line in space.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You use UIBezierPath and drawRect()

Comment: @Arbitur But the path has no z axis

Comment: Is that really needed?

Answer (score 1):

Normal drawing on iOS is 2D. Core Animation is "2.5D", where it can draw flat images with fake 3D perspective. It doesn't let you "draw in space."

If you want real 3D perspective drawing you should use OpenGL, SceneKit, Metal, or some other 3D API.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to draw a 3d image on a 2d surface. Therefore you need some sort of mapping

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Has some options for you. Orthographic projection is probably what you want though

https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/3/a/83a402b37056afa1dd4c8d706a9a2d75.png

Is the equation you would want to use where s is a scaling factor and c is an offset

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have finished the 2d surface rotate in space use CATransform3D already. But I don't know how to draw line in space.Would you mind showing me how to accomplish it?